# Atlassian FishEye plugin and Spring LDAP classes

Tags: java, maven, plugins, spring-security-ldap, atlassian-fisheye

My plugin for FishEye should have a possibility to accessing the our Active Directory and implement some more features for FishEye. The plugin should make the synchronization with directory every X minutes, so it is based on SAL Scheduler.
When I tried to use com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, I found that is works only with REST plugin, but using with SAL does not load this classes even when I re-defined the classloader.
Anyway, I re-implemented my functionality with the Spring LDAP and when I tried to deploy my plugin to the FishEye I got:

```
2014-12-03 23:12:03,010 ERROR [ThreadPoolAsyncTaskExecutor::Thread 9 ] org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.activator.ContextLoaderListener DefaultOsgiBundleApplicationContextListener-onOsgiApplicationEvent - Application context refresh failed (NonValidatingOsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=com.mycompany.fisheye.ldap-restriction-plugin, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml))
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi]
Offending resource: URL [bundle://84.0:0/META-INF/spring/atlassian-plugins-component-imports.xml]
```

Ok. I googled and found https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/faq/troubleshooting/dependency-issues-during-plugin-initialisation
There is written that I have to change the scope of dependency to **provided** for avoiding the conflicts. Ok, I made that. But now I have another exception:

```
Exception in thread "PluginSchedulerTask-com.mycompany.fisheye.LdapRestrictio    nComponentImpl:job" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ldap/core/support/LdapContextSource
```

I tried to put the spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar to $fisheyeDir/lib and nothing happens - the bootloader does not pick up this JAR.

Does anybody know what can be done in this situation? Should I use another LDAP framework or it is possible to shove these ldap client implementation to the classpath?

FishEye version 3.6.1 (latest), spring jars into classpath version 3.0.5.RELEASE. My spring-security-ldap dependency is also 3.0.5.RELEASE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring version FishEye uses internally (3.0.5 in 3.6.1, 3.1.4 as of 3.7), is not exposed to plugins.

Instead they get a spring runtime from the Atlassian plugin system (https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-plugins). FishEye uses plugins 3.0.x, so the Spring version that's available to plugins is 2.5.6.

Neither FishEye, the plugin system nor any of the bundled plugins include spring-ldap, so you can't set the dependency scope to  (as this causes the library not to be included in the plugin jar, instead expecting it be available via an OSGI import).

So what I believe you should try is to bundle a version of spring-ldap that's compatible with Spring 2.5.6. To solve the BeanDefinitionParsingException, you might need to exclude some transitive dependencies that are provided by the plugin system (use mvn dependency:tree to find those).

Disclosure: I'm a dev working on FishEye/Crucible

Comment: miszobi, thanks for your answer!

The plugin is already finished and permanently works on our FishEye instance. I have used UnboundID SDK and removed all Spring code and now all is good.